# Learning Math Efficienctly and Succeeding in Grad School

Tags: soft-question, intuition, self-learning, education, advice

I'm currently a second year Ph.D. student studying pure math.  I've recently come to the conclusion that I must be studying wrong.  Actually, more to the point, I must be thinking about mathematics wrong.  It's not that I'm failing, quite to the contrary, so far I have been very successful in the program, the problem is that I don't *feel* like I'm learning and absorbing the material the way I should be.

I want to become comfortable friends with the objects of mathematical study.  I want to know their quirks and behaviour.  I want to feel like I am part of the mathematics and not just an outside observer.  But so far my experience is totally the opposite.  I have become a competent symbol and logic manipulator but this has made my recent experience with mathematics cold and detached. Even though I can solve difficult problems, complete problem sets, and pass qualifying exams my knowledge is disjoint and compartmentalized, and my intuition is surface level.

At my school it is mandatory that we take three classes so having three problem sets due (or more commonly 2 will overlap at all times) from the three classes creates a constant stream of pressure to solve problems.

I'm curious to know if I am alone in feeling this way.  For those of you who have been through graduate school (or anyone with relevant advice): Did you feel like you were getting a deep understanding of the material?  Ultimately the question is this:

> Does anyone have advice for how to deeply understand a new mathematical object efficiently?
>
> Specifically how to become comfortable with a new object (definition, theorem, "chunk" of a theory) efficiently, be able to recognize the object from different perspectives, and be able to see how it fits into a larger picture.

As an example stolen from Thurston's "On Proof and Progress" we can view the derivative in several different ways

1. As a limit
2. Slope of the tangent line
3. Linear approximation
4. What the function looks like around a point under increasing magnification
5. etc

Thank You!

Comment: I'm in the same position with courses. The constant stream of assignments being due with two assignments due in the same week (often on the same day) is really making it difficult for me to truly understand the material. Sometimes I have three due in one week. With TA duties and tutoring on the side, I'm finding it difficult to properly internalize material because I just don't have enough time in the day because I'm kind of slow when it comes to assignments/concepts because I have a weak background. My weeks end up being 80 hour weeks just for TA/tutoring/assignments. Grad school is tough.

Comment: Yes, this is similar to my experience.  Problem sets take long enough that it eats away time that could have been spent reflecting and absorbing.  It seems the paradigm is either meant for a different kind of learner or possibly its just broken

Comment: I don't mean to be glib but: "Young man, in mathematics you don't understand things. You just get used to them." John von Neumann.

Comment: @shaun an interesting quote, but then the question becomes, how long does it take to get used to something, is there an efficient way to approach this?  For example, I could get used to the layout of a new campus by going on several scavanger hunts to the more hidden places of campus, but it might take me a while to really understand the layout of the campus because I'm focused so intensely on the hunt (read solving problems) where as another approach would be to look at a map or just walk around and note the large picture layout and then fill in the details after.  Which is more efficient?

Comment: @mike vaiana: Indeed. However, it sounds to me like you're already 'used to things' to some extent, but I'm in no position to say so. I just thought it might comfort you; you're in good company (if the quote can be taken as it stands).

Comment: You ask: "Specifically how to become comfortable with a new [whatever] efficiently, be able to recognize it from different perspectives, and be able to see how it fits into a larger picture." The concept of a larger picture is misleading. As there is no end to this process–there's always is a larger picture to be concerned about. If I were to be obnoxious, I would ask "can you fully comprehend the meaning of a number 2?" (meaning that if you did, then you would have to know all the theorems that involve this number, etc.). It is good to know different perspectives, but don't make it your goal.

Comment: @Shaun  Oh right, now I understand the point of the quote, and thank you, it is somewhat of a comfort to be in good company in that regard!

Comment: @dtldarek  Yes, I agree with that.  Asking to see all perspectives is too much (in fact I might argue that is the ultimate and unending goal of all mathematics) But I think it is reasonable to attempt to view a new object from at least one addition perspective.  For example if I am thinking about modular arthemitic then 2 fits into the theory by encoding even and odd.  So within the given theory I realize some familar object in a different way.  In linear algebra 2 characterizes a vector space (with a fixed ground field). The list goes on, but how do I get to this point with "new" objects.

Comment: One way to get around problem sets is to do reading courses. At my grad program, I think you are required to take *some* "official" courses, but not many. I did a reading course this semester and I got a lot out of it. You can still attend lectures by auditing. That way you'll have the benefit of being a student in the course, but you won't feel obligated to do homework. I've started to approach lectures as I approach books - get from them what you want but feel free to wander. This is much easier if you're auditing. I can't say that my professors would agree with me though.

Comment: @DylonChow I agree completely!  I realized after talking to people from different departments that my university has more stringent course requirements.  We need 7 registered grad students for a course to run (even a seminar) and so they force us to register for 12 credits every semester for our entire time in the program.  I am doing a reading course this semester though and it is making a world of difference, my question basically no longer applies it was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

You really want to give your world of math another dimension where math sheds a light on you differently? Go into teaching. Rather than aiming for your students to become proficient at your level, you need to go down to their level and together meet the goals of the course curriculum. It's that aim to think at your students' math level to go through the material while you teach, that puts the math knowledge you aquired through the years in a different perspective. You will be so surprised how much you learn your own subject when teaching it to others.

Comment: I fully agree that teaching helps one learn the material in a completely different and often more thorough way.  But first, I don't have an audience for such a thing, and second I think one has to have an understanding of the material at least 1 level deeper than a textbook before one can teach the material at all (otherwise one would just be orating the textbook) My question is really about how to get to that level, 1 level deeper, and then from there how do you go deeper than that.

Comment: You don't need to go into teaching at the level where you are with your current studies. You could teach an undergrad level course, say a calculus course. Eventhough we both are done with that in our own studies, I can reassure you that after having taught calculus for a decade or so, I am still learning undergrad material, through the experience of teaching (and teaching it differently as a "try out"), in fact, I am still learning undergrad stuff from this website. We have Master's but are we honestly fully competent in each and every undergrad field of math?

Comment: I understand your point.  And in this case I fully agree with you.  I suppose I am not so interested in getting a better understanding of calculus as I feel that I understand that particular subject well (not that I fully understand it)  I was more interested in a way to understand $new$ material that I haven't encountered before.

Comment: I was referring to your reference of Thurston's which are calculus based. But as far as new material goes, how well do you do in self study of new material? Because I think that's where your challenge lies...

Comment: I actually prefer self study, it gives me the opportunity to read, think, re-read, question, come up with examples and finally attempt to solve problems.  I guess part of this whole post is that I'm frustrated that I don't have time to do this because I am constantly being forced to turn in problem sets which eat up a large chunk of every week.

Comment: As a third year PhD student, I don't know how qualified I am to give advice, but let me say that you can "teach" material to your classmates as you learn it. I find it very helpful to try to explain what I am doing, even on problems, to other graduate students in lower years or to classmates in a slightly different area.It forces me to understand my own thinking, especially on a big-picture level.

Comment: I agree with you on this one as long as you really like the material, have an inclination to learn it easy and...have the time to do all the prep. Mike seems to have an issue here.

Comment: Yes, the time to do all the prep is the issue, I definitely agree that this is a good method for learning something on a deeper level, its just that if I had the time to prep something like this I would need to ask the question in the first place :)